# $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']

Tags: php

$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] элемент суперглобального массива, из которого можно вытащить предпочитаемый язык посетителя, так вот, требуется список всех возможных соответвий сокращений для языков, как пример:

```
ru - Русский
en - Английский
fr - Французкий
es - Испанский
```

Comment: предлагаю"не для того, чтоб бараны обсуждали, а как дельное на мой взгляд, предложение":
не перекидывать польз-ля на страницу с нужным ему языком, а сделать <форму> с выбором языка, куда ему перейти! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ISO 639-1](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.A2.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.B8.D1.86.D0.B0_.D1.81_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B8_.D1.8F.D0.B7.D1.8B.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B2)

Answer (score 1):

Там ISO 639-1 с субтэгами (регион, диалект, письменность и т.п.).
Вот этот список рекомендую: 
[IANA Language Subtag Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry)

Comment: Что за источник насколько достоверен? Насколько я знаю, 639-1 использует 2-буквенные сокращения.

Comment: Оп-па! Источник — IANA. Куда уж достовернее.
Двухбуквенное сокращение — это только код языка по ISO 639-1. А дальше идут субтэги.

Спецификация поля в этом заголовке такая: 

language-tag  = primary-tag *( "-" subtag )

Пример:

en, en-US, en-cockney, i-cherokee, x-pig-latin

то есть это могут быть _не_только_ две буквы для каждого языка.

Comment: Так намного понятней, спасибо )